# C++ object data being wiped clean after function goes out of scope

Tags: c++, scope, pass-by-reference

CS student here, first post.

I am working with two objects. `obj1` is passed to `obj2` by reference. `obj2` processes data from a file and writes information to a char[] in `obj1`. `obj1` then evaluates the information in the char array.

However, as soon as the function in `obj2` that has been writing to the char[] goes out of scope, all the information that has been written is wiped clean. I have stepped through the code and it's clear to me that `obj1` is not being passed by reference, but I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me see what I'm missing?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //...
    Object1 obj1;   // obj1 created with &1
    Object2 obj2(filename, obj1);
    obj2.func1();   // void function that writes to obj1.arr -> writes fine but to a obj1.arr @ &2
    obj1.func1();   // obj1.arr @ &2 is gone, obj1.arr @ &1 is garbage.
}

// Object1.h
class Object1
{
    Object1() = default;
    char arr[size];
}

// Object2.h
class Object2 
{
    public: 
        Object1 obj1;
        string filename;
}

// Object2.cpp
Object2::Object2(string filename, Object1& obj1)
    : filename(filename), obj1(obj1)
{
}
```

Comment: In your class definition, change the Object1 obj1 member in Object2 to Object1& obj1

Comment: But probably there will be an error, so better change it to Object *obj1 and work with pointers instead. This way, you pass your pointer to object 1 via the & (&obj1) and you access to it's members via the arrow operator -> - See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ for details

Comment: Does obj1 have a [copy constructor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm)?

Comment: @DarthMoon I think using reference also should work. Why do you feel it will be an error?

Comment: I had trouble initialozing an already declared reference, but probably this was in an other case ... Googled the problem ... Everything is OK. Use references and live long with C++ :)

Comment: @Chipster not one I've defined.

Comment: Hmm. 'Cause your constructor for obj2 should make a copy of the data, but since you don't have one, it uses the default behavior, which for arr[] specifically I think is to make them point to the same physical memory. That is to say, writing in obj2 should show up in obj1. IT's not good design (good design would be making a copy constructor and passing storing a reference instead), but should theoretically work. But I'm glad someone else got it working for you.

Comment: @Chipster: No, an array member physically exists inside its parent object, and copying works correctly.  There is no pointer at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt but aren't arrays and pointers the same thing in C++? Or can you only reference them the same way?

Comment: @Chipster: No, they are nothing alike.  The confusion comes from the fact that there exists an implicit conversion from an array to a pointer (called "decay") -- but declaration of a class member is not one of the places where decay happens.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, like doubles and ints, which are nothing alike, but can be converted to each other. I think I know the problem then. It's making a copy of the array and thus obj2 is not writing to obj1, but rather a cc of it. The OP must mean to make arr a pointer, or means to store a reference, as others have mentioned.

Comment: @Chipster: Sort of, but while `int` and `double` are different types, they're the same kind of type.  Both are scalar numeric primitive types.  On the other hand, an array is an aggregate (it has sub-objects) and provides data storage, while a pointer is a scalar and creates an alias to data storage owned by another object (They do have in common that they both are compound types, dependent on some element type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be here:

```
// Object2.h
class Object2 
{
    public: 
       Object1 obj1;
```

Note that `Object2` has a member-variable named `obj1`, and that your `Object2` constructor is initializing that member-variable using the reference that was passed in as an argument to the constructor:

```
 Object2::Object2(string filename, Object1& obj1)
    : filename(filename), obj1(obj1)
 {
```

Note also that the meaning of `obj1(obj1)` isn't obvious here -- you've named your second constructor argument `obj1`, but you also have the local member-variable named `obj1`.  In order to avoid ambiguity for the human reader, you should change either the name of the argument or the name of the member-variable.

You may also want to change the type of your Object2 class's member-variable from `Object1` to `Object1 &`, if your intent is that the `Object2` object should be continue to reference the original `obj1` object directly rather than use its own separate `Object1` member-object.

Comment: The last paragraph is the only thing that's important, there is no ambiguity inside the initializer (as far as the compiler is concerned -- it certainly can be confusing to programmers)

Comment: Oh?  How does the compiler know which `obj1` is being referred to inside the parentheses?

Comment: "Names in the *expression-list* or *braced-init-list* of a *mem-initializer* are evaluated in the scope of the constructor for which the *mem-initializer* is specified."  in `[class.base.init]` and there's a direct example of parameter and member with the same name.  In that scope, the parameter name hides the member name.  The *mem-initializer-id*, unlike the *expression-list*, is looked up in the class scope, and finds the member.

Comment: That did it. Changing `Object1` to `Object1&` made all the difference. Thank you very much for the help-I've been trying to fix this all night.

Comment: Due to its inherent none-copyablity and none-movability, using a reference as a class data member is discouraged. You may consider pointers for that purpose.

Comment: @Red.Wave: What?  References copy and move just fine.  Perhaps you meant that they break assignment?

Comment: @BenVoigt ouch! you got me.